# Importing an .eps file failed in the latest version of mathematica

Tags: import, eps-format

It was quite straight forward to import an .eps file (also pdf and other formats) into a script, with the version 10.0. that I had before; but, since I upgraded my *Mathematica* to the latest version 10.4.1, it fails and the following message appears:

> "Unable to communicate with closed link \
>   !(LinkObject[\"'/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Converters/Binaries/MacOSX-x86-64/PDF.exe'\", 165, 4]). "

The command is simply:

```
graphPMF03 = Import["Desktop/myfile.eps"];
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell what might be going on. Can you open the file with another program? Esp. can you open with it Ghostscript/GhostView?

Comment: I would contact Wolfram Technical Support with a copy of the file that isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

THIS IS AN EXTENDED COMMENT RATHER THAN AN ANSWER.

```
$Version

(*  "10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"  *)

plt = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
Export["Desktop/myfile.eps", plt];

plt2 = Import["Desktop/myfile.eps"]
```

[image]

The tick labels are missing although they appear when the `eps` file is opened in another application (e.g., `Preview`). However, export/import of `pdf` format appears to work as expected.

```
Export["Desktop/myfile.pdf", plt];

plt3 = Import["Desktop/myfile.pdf"][[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: I can confirm this incorrect Import behavior for .eps in Mathematica 10.4.1 under Mac OS X 10.11.5.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to Import an EPS file with Mathematica 11.1 and have the same problem. It just doesn't work. Was this reported as a "bug" and if so did you get a response?